# Simple Snowflake Update Statement Taking Over An Hour

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to run an update statement on a test Snowflake table. As of now, it has taken over an hour for a one column update statement. The table is about 33bil rows and 5tb and I was wondering if that could be the reason for such a slow update as it's my first time updating a table in Snowflake. My update statement looks like:

```
UPDATE Source1.TestTable
SET 
    Column1 = CASE WHEN year(SourceTable.Column2) >= 1800 
        THEN SourceTable.Column2
        ELSE NULL END
        FROM Source2.SourceTable;
```

Comment: I am inclined to think it is due to the large number of rows in the table that its taking a long time. The following steps might help you: a. Index column 2 and column 1. b. unless there is  a reason to handle this update in one transaction, I would recommend doing it in batches. That will prevent the transaction log to get super fat before the changes are committed.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your help. I need to make sure this case is applied to this column for the entire table. Batches might be my best bet as of now!

Comment: What is the relationship between `Source1.TestTable` and `Source2.SourceTable`? Seems like you need a `JOIN` after `FROM Source2.SourceTable`.

Comment: Yea, seems like you are missing a join

Comment: Source2.SourceTable holds data that will be passed to Source1.TestTable. The insert sql used to pass this data has transformations that will be present in Source1.TestTable.

Comment: Which sql you are using? The reason it is important to have some form of join is that in your query SourceTable is used to update TestTable but no relationship is defined between them.  The format in T-Sql would be something like :     update a set a.column = case when year( b.col) > xxxx then b.col else null end  from table1 a join table2 b on a.someCol = b.someCol

Comment: Please see the first example here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/update.html . Like @ShivSidhu said, you're missing a join. Careful though, as unlike in T-SQL, you should NOT reuse the target table in the FROM clause. Again, read the doc please :)